# Shortest way to turn a regular IEnumerable collection into a DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, extension-methods, wpfdatagrid

I'm not used to working with *DataTables* and all its built in functionalities, rather I usually use it for its debug visual display feature.

I'm new to WPF, and although I am experienced with linq/IEnumerable extension methods, I learned that a DataGrid, in order to support editing, the object you assigned to the *ItemsSource* property must implement a given interface (which I am not sure what it is, for the time being let's say it is either IEditableCollectionView or IBindingList).

Since I am used to collection manipulations via IEnumerable extension methods, here is how I easily manipulate a datatable, filter it and project only the columns I want:

```
        grdSettings.ItemsSource =
                _settings
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(row => row["table"].ToString().Equals(e.AddedItems[0].ToString()))
                .Select(s => new
                    {
                        Setting = s["field"],
                        Description = s["description"],
                        CharValue = s["charValue"],
                        NumMinValue = s["minValue"],
                        NumMaxValue = s["maxValue"]
                    });
```

The problem with this is that the grid will not be editable. If I assign _settings.AsDataView(), the grid is editable. My problem then is I do not want all the columns, and I cannot make (I do not know how) an IEnumerable into a DataView. I read some posts about filtering columns from a datatable/dataview, but the solutions look a bit awkward, not as smooth as I would like...

Isn't there only a small piece I am missing I can "plug" into my solution, instead of having to give up the IEnumerable extension methods filtering... ?

---

**Update**: *Mike Eason* below suggested replacing my anonymous type with a predefined one, stating anonymous types are read only and this is the reason why the grid's collection source does not support editing.

here's the update with a strongly typed object, but it still does not work. Actually it does not make sense to think this alone would make it work, based on the premise stated above, that in order for a grid to allow editing its collection source object must implement a given interface for that.

```
        grdSettings.ItemsSource =
                _settings
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(row => row["table"].ToString().Equals(e.AddedItems[0].ToString()))
                .Select(s => new GridRecord
                    {
                        Setting = s["field"].ToString(),
                        Description = s["description"].ToString(),
                        CharValue = s["charValue"].ToString(),
                        NumMinValue = s["minValue"].ToString(),
                        NumMaxValue = s["maxValue"].ToString()
                    });
```

Comment: Well, I found the framework offers https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx... I need however to create a type for my projection, because it seems only a List of DataRow supports CopyToDataTable

Comment: Anonymous types are read only, this is why your DataView is not editable. Instead of selecting an anonymous type, you could perhaps select a new **class type**.

Comment: @MikeEason, I tried what you suggest, but it does not help.

Comment: The https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataTableProxy package will make a DataTable out of a regular IEnumerable<T>. In the absence of any better/simpler solution, I have dropped the datatable from my code, and used List<List<string>> instead (because I do not want to create a 2nd instance of a datatable just for the sake of editing the grid) - and am making a DataTable out of it using the package. I have my editable grid, but I am still optimistic of simpler solutions :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of better solutions, I made use of the [DataTableProxy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataTableProxy) nuget package, which will make a DataTable out of a regular `IEnumerable<T>`, dropped the datatable from my code, and used `List<List<string>>` instead (because I do not want to create a 2nd instance of a datatable just for the sake of editing the grid) -  making a DataTable out of it using the package.

I have my editable grid, but I am still optimistic about simpler solutions :-)